# Travis CI: Test build is not finishing after successfull tests

Tags: angular, karma-runner, travis-ci

Travis CI build my Angular app and all test are passing:

```
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
e 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.137 secs)
e 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.178 secs)
'0 -  {"isTrusted":true}'
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.178 secs)
ERROR: '0 -  {"isTrusted":true}'
TypeError{}
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.178 secs)
LOG: TypeError{}
e 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.391 secs)
'0 -  {"isTrusted":true}'
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.391 secs)
ERROR: '0 -  {"isTrusted":true}'
TypeError{}
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.391 secs)
LOG: TypeError{}
e 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.512 secs)
e 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.538 secs)
e 59.0.3071 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 SUCCESS (0.556 secs / 0.538 secs)
```

After all tests are passed, the build is still running, and after 10 minutes the build fails due to inactivity.

```
"No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received
The build has been terminated"
```

My karma.conf:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },

    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true // tried false aswell
  });
};
```

Any idea what I'm missing? Is there any way to mark the test build as complete?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the --exit to your package.json file

```
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js",
      "test": "mocha --exit"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have `autoWatch: true` turned on? So Karma is still running, waiting for your test files to change?

Comment: when `autoWatch` is false the CI don't test the files (and stills times out). I tried CircleCI with and without autowatch, and it passed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set autoWatch to false and that should do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ng test --watch=false` in your package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false"
  }
```